# Populate production server with fixture data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, seeding

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I just setup my heroku account.

My question is what is the difference between seed data and fixture data? I want to put my test fixtures up onto heroku. My test fixtures work fine in my development environment. Do I need to convert them to seed data? Can I just push my fixtures to my production server. If so how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your fixture yamls are on your Heroku (they should be unless you specifically excluded them from git), you can run the follow command to populate your Heroku database:

```
heroku run rake db:fixtures:load
```

That being said, this is a horrible practice. Fixture data is not validated, unlike seed data. You do not want unvalidated data entering a production database.

Comment: Hey Thomas, Thank you for your help! I see what you mean about validations. I ran what you said anyways, and it worked fine. In the future I should populate with my seed data instead, correct?

Comment: Glad I could help. And yes, in the future use seed data :)